# Can a Mayor be used to create a Castle?

Tags: carcassonne

We combined Abbey & Mayor with Bridges, Castles & Bazaars for the first time last night, and one situation cropped up for which I want to clarify the rules.

I created a small city (with no banners), as defined for the Castle requirements, but only had a Mayor to hand.  The Mayor rules state:

> When a city containing a mayor is scored, ...

IE the banner / number of followers rule doesn't come into play here as the city -> castle is specifically not a scoring event.

The Castle rules state:

> ... the owner of the city chooses whether to score 4 points, as normal, or to make it into a castle.

The CAR changes "owner" to "occupier", but otherwise is more or less the same.  Since I'm not scoring, my reading is that the Mayor is the owner/occupier.

Is my interpretation correct - can a Mayor become a lord in a castle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short and simple answer: The mayor **cannot** be placed in a castle.
(From footnote 161 in the [Carcassonne Complete Annotated Rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/87531/carcassonne-standard-complete-annotated-rules))

If the mayor is in a city that is turned into a castle, you won't get any points from the mayor as there are no banners in a castle. In that case, the mayor will not be returned to you until the castle is scored (that is to say, an adjacent structure is completed).

Comment: Thanks - I missed that footnote!  Was looking more under the castles section.  May be worth mentioning that this footnote takes the form of an official clarification.